# Help defining the correct relationship between two tables

Tags: database-design

I am working on the implementation of a point of sale system for restaurants, in my question I need to know the relationship that exists between the entities tables and orders, based on the following conditions

- A customer can be served at a table.
- A client can request to join several tables in consequence the order of this client can have several tables.

The current idea is that I should create a table called for example order_table with a many-to-many relationship between tables and orders or it should be a one-to-many relationship between orders and order_table.

Based on the conditions that I mention what you think would be the best solution to this case.

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply you should have these Tables

- Customer: Which Represents some information about your Clients
- Order: Which Represents Information about the Orders your customers are making, of course you should have a CustomerID field in this table which references Customer(CustomerID)
- Table:  each Restaurant can have some Tables which you are storeing information about Tables in this [Database table]
- OrderTables : in order to Relate Orders with Tables you should use  this Table which you will have a structure as {OrderID , TableID} in this Table 
  so it will be a one-to-many Relation